# Concatenate char array and int array and store in string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, int

I would like to concatenate `char` array and the `int` array and store them in another `char` array. How could I do that?

Here is the code so far

```
char letter[100];
int number[100], i;

char * letterNum[100];

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 letterNum[i] = strcat(letter[i], number[i]);
}
```

expected output should be

> a1
>  b1
>  ...

Comment: What is a `string array`? [Hint: you already told `char array`]

Answer (score 2):

The `strcat()` function concatenates strings not `char`s, you need `sprintf()`

```
sprintf(letterNum[i], "%c%d", letter[i], number[i]);
```

and also, `letterNum` in your case is an array of pointers, it should be an array of arrays, like

```
char letterNum[100][3];
```

and then, you can use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` to prevent buffer overflow

```
if (snprintf(letterNum[i], 3, "%c%d", letter[i], number[i]) > 2)
    youHaveToDoSomethin_An_Error_Occurred();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess Mr. [Iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931925/2173917) your question, but just to elaborate a bit more,

Let's see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`. It says,

> `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`

which means it expects both the arguments to be pointer to *strings*. Now, as we know, a pointer to `int` array cannot be considered a *string*, we cannot use `strcat()` directly in your case.

So, what you have to do is,

- Take another buffer
- *Copy* both the contents of the `char` array and `int` array elements for particular index one after another in *lexicographical* format, so that the final result is the *concatenation* of both.

Now, you have [`sprintf()`/ `snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to help you out in this case. It prints the formatted o/p to the supplied *string*.

A pseudo-code

```
char letter[100];   //populating value, not shown
int number[100];    //populating value, not shown

int i = 0;

char letterNum[100][32];

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 if ( sprintf(letterNum[i], "%c%d", letter[i], number[i]) != 2)
             printf("Error in %d iteration\n", (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help! 
I guess, I need to try an error and test it out myself... the explaination was clear and helpful... plus given codes for me to eeasily understand...
Your kind help is greatly aappreciated.. Thank you once again